# Matlab: Select items from vector

Tags: arrays, matlab, vector, indexing

I have a vector or a matrix where I want to select rows.
The vector could look like this

```
T{1} = 'A'
T{2} = 'B'
T{3} = 'A'
```

and I want to reduce it from ABA to AA using

```
T([ 1 0 1])
```

but that does not compile, if I do

```
T([ 1 2 3])
```

I get the original. However I select the rows using a strfind function like this

```
indexlistM = cell2mat(strfind(T, 'A')) = [1 0 1];
```

How can I select rows using a true/false selector or using a different method?

Comment: One issue with your post: `strfind(T, 'A')` is the cell array `{[1], [], [1]}`, applying `cell2mat` to this yields `[1 1]`, not `[1 0 1]`.

Comment: You should use `strcmp(T, 'A')` or `contains(T, 'A')`, depending on your logic (the first one is true if the string is equal, the second is true if it contains the pattern).

Answer (score 1):

The error you got for running this

```
T([1 0 1])
```

is quite descriptive

> Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.

You have provided a non-positive integer (`0`) which isn't a logical (`false`).

You can either do

```
T( [true false true] ); % = T( logical([1 0 1]) )
```

MATLAB sometimes obfuscates the type for logical arrays (which can make this confusing) because it's easier to display and read logicals in numeric format, but to *use* logical indexing you need the array to be an actual logical type, not a double

```
[true false true]
ans =
  1×3 logical array
   1   0   1
```

Or use the index

```
T( [1 3] )
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea how to provide a logical array or an index is already answered.
Here I want to demonstrate the solution with code examples:

```
contains(T, 'A')
ans =
  1×3 logical array
   1   0   1
```

or using an index with `find`

```
find(contains(T, 'A'))
ans =
 1     3
```

In both cases the result is

```
  1×2 cell array
    {'A'}    {'A'}
```